# Can't print the second page on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

I just encountered an issue that my print result is not what I expected.

My main template code is

```
<div class="row" style="width:97%;margin:0 auto;">
        <!-- 종합 평가 -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0;">
            {% include 'silver/silver_evaluation_form_result_table_new.html'%}
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0;">
            {% include 'silver/silver_evaluation_each_exdata_result.html'%}
        </div>
        <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0;">
            {% include 'silver/silver_compare_page_new.html' %}
        </div>
 </div>
```

The problem happens between `silver_evaluation_each_exdata` and `silver_compare_page_new`. I expected that my silver_compare_page-new will be printed at the second page but it doesn't.

IE prints the second page with a blank content. It is just blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it the right way and read this and do it like this? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp (Those css are not taken in consideration on media screen and there are only accounted only on media print)

```
@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

Having css inline is not recommended and it should be avoided all the time. Try giving the divs some classes and defined them in a separate css file.